# "Improve on" Usage

Tags: meaning, usage, phrasal-verbs

I have a question about the usage of the phrase "*improve on*".  Dictionary definitions suggest that the usage of "*improve on*" should follow this pattern:

> <doer> *improve on* <result>

So, the phrase "*improve on*" should involve a doer doing something and producing results, like:

> 1. The companies ***improved on*** last year's sales.
> 2. He ***improved on*** last year's performance.

But on the web, I found [this](http://entertainment.ie/life/Incredibly-sound-boss-cuts-his-salary-and-raises-the-minimum-to-dollar70000/361927.htm):

> He will also receive a salary of $70,000, and claims that he won't be taking a pay rise either until the company's profits ***improve on*** last year's mark of $2.2 million.

, which has the following pattern:

> <result> *improve on* <result>

, which does not seem to fit dictionary definitions.  Could this usage be wrong?  Or, could dictionaries be missing a better definition that fits the "<result> improve on <result>" pattern?

Comment: The company's profits [doer, albeit somewhat abstract] *improve on* last years's mark [result]. Where's the problem?

Comment: @Stephie  "Profits" is more a "*result*" than a "*doer*".

Comment: Don't read "logic", read "grammar": *who* improves on *what*. And focus only on that snippet.

Comment: "Dictionary definitions suggest that the usage of "improve on" should follow this pattern: `<doer> improve on <result>`" `<doer>` is an odd looking term in dictionaries, so this idea is your own, perhaps? Could you add a real definition from a dictionary to your question?

Comment: @DamkerngT.  Then for [this](https://stanfordhealthcare.org/medical-tests/p/pet-ct-scan.html), "How a combined PET/CT scan ***improves on*** separate scans "
is "*improve on*" used correctly?

Comment: @meatie I believe that I had already answered that in a comment that is now deleted. In the case that I didn't say anything explicitly, I agree with Stephie in her comment.

Answer (score 2):

After searching my usual dictionaries I fail to see *any* definition that uses the terms `doer` or `result`.
I presume that what you really mean is `subject` and `(noun) phrase`.

Sources vary whether `improve on / upon` is considered a *phrasal* verb or not, but the *pattern* remains constant:

> [subject] *improve on / upon* [noun phrase]

Comment: Then for [this](https://stanfordhealthcare.org/medical-tests/p/pet-ct-scan.html):  
"How a combined PET/CT scan ***improves on*** separate scans", is "*improve on*" used correctly?

Comment: Yes it is. The combined scan is better than (understood as "improves the results of") separate scans.

Comment: Would this rewrite "How a combined PET/CT scan ***improves on the results of*** separate scans" be better?

Comment: @meatie Gut feeling: yes. But I'm no biologist or technician.

Answer (score 1):

"Improve on" is a phrasal verb.

The verb improve can be used transitively or intransitively; it means to make something better than before or to become better than before.

The preposition "on" is also used in the sense of "compared with". Look at the [entry #22](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/british/on) under "on" in Macmillan Dictionary (This would be a significant improvement on £15 million profit figure achieved last year).

So The following sentences are correct grammatically:

1. The company has improved on last year's profit.
2. The company's profit has improved on last year's profit.

The OP's so-called structure result + improve on + result definitely fits well in the sentence #2 mentioned above.

Comment: Then for [this](https://stanfordhealthcare.org/medical-tests/p/pet-ct-scan.html), "How a combined PET/CT scan ***improves on*** separate scans "
is "*improve on*" used correctly?

Answer (score 0):

When you see a *seemingly* phrasal verb constructed with a verb and a preposition such as ***improve on***, you have to figure out why there is ***on*** as it is more likely that the preposition has nothing to do with the verb used. In other words, you have to separate the two words and figure each out.

***On*** in your examples mean:

> Having (the thing mentioned) ***as a basis***.

In other words, you can change it to ***on the basis of***, or even ***compared with***.

> The companies improved on last year's sales.

It means "***this year's sales of the company*** increased (improved) ***compared with/on the basis of*** last year's sales".

> He improved on last year's performance.

It means "***his performance this year*** increased (improved) ***compared with/on the basis of*** last year's performance".

> ... until the company's profits improve on last year's mark of $2.2
>   million.

This means "until the company's profits increase (improve) ***compared with/on the basis of*** last year's mark of $2.2 million.

***Compared with*** fits in better than ***on the basis of***, but I put it there for comparison.

As you can see, the subject of the verb *improve* has nothing to do with the construction.

***Edit:*** Just because ***improve on something*** means ***better than something*** doesn't necessarily mean that you can apply it to all context. Here,  ***to improve on something*** means ***to produce better results in comparison with something***. However, if you say, "He improves on her", you can never know what kind of results you are talking about. That's why the sentence doesn't work and you could only ***guess the meaning***.